# Add data to JQuery Form

Tags: javascript, jquery

First of I admit that I am really bad at js and just got started. I have this snippet in the repository:

```
function sendReport() {
    $.post($('#reportForm').attr('action') + '/post', $("#reportForm").serialize()).done(function() {
      reportManager.run();
    });
}
```

And I want to add data to it. I want the webservice that is receiving the post to receive an additional key/value-pair. I tried something like

```
var data = $('#reportForm').serializeArray();
data.push({name: 'stuff', value: 'blaha'});

$.post(data, $("#reportForm").serialize()).done(function() {
    reportManager.run();
});
```

Didn't work at all and I would really appreciate any help with this.

EDIT:

Tried doing the suggestion below, didn't work. Tried this just to verify that the new parameter didn't ruin anything:

```
//data to post
var data = $('#reportForm').serializeArray();

//url to post
var url = $('#reportForm').attr('action') + '/post';

//options required for jQuery.post
var options = { "data":data, "url": url };

$.post(options).done(function() {
    reportManager.run();
});
```

That doesn't work. I'm getting an error like this on the server:

```
noHandlerFound No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/[object Object]]
```

I am considering that something else in the code might be using some implicit behaviour, but I find it strange that trying the code above(without even adding new data) can break the current working behaviour.

Comment: the first parameter of jquery post must be an uri?

Comment: Buddy, always start with api documentation, not stackoverflow: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Comment: reportManager.run() provides the uri. Before my modifications the post is working fine.

Comment: @why_vincent: You are not providing valid parameters to a method call

Comment: your first parameter seems to be an array, not string

Comment: @why_vincent: the error you specified is coming from the server it self saying there is not method/webservice which can handle the request you have made. I would suggest you to use chrome developer tool and Network tab specifically where you can see what request was made and with what parameters that might narrow down your issue.
https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network-performance/

Comment: @why_vincent: Is the code you posted previously, still working?

Answer (score 2):

You are not providing uri parameter for post method, you should use something similar to:

```
//data to post
var data = $('#reportForm').serializeArray();
data.push({name: 'stuff', value: 'blaha'});

//url to post
var url = $('#reportForm').attr('action') + '/post';

//options required for jQuery.post
var options = { "data":data, "url": url };

$.post(options).done(function() {
    reportManager.run();
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion. Didn't work however. I have edited my post. Since performing the operation above without the push breaks behaviour then it must do more than just add a piece of data. Could there be anything else that has to be done? This might be a strange exceptional case. As I said I am new to js so this is a bit of a mystery to me and your help is greatly appreciated.